# The use of contexts in a Drupal.t() function in Javascript

Tags: 8, javascript

According to the documentation, we can use contexts with `Drupal.t()` since Drupal 8.

`Drupal.t('May', {}, {context: "Long month name"});` works fine, but `Drupal.t('May', {}, {context: "Abbreviated month name"});` doesn't translate *May*.

Why?

Comment: How are you determining it doesn't work?

Comment: In French it must return "Mai" ... but it returns "May".

Comment: Have you translated the string in the new context already?

Comment: Of course... in php the t('May', {}, {context: "Abbreviated month name"}) works fine

Comment: Please provide more feedback, for example the code, expected output and actual output of what is currently working, the same for what is not working, and maybe a bit more info around it, that helps people here to help you.